# How does RAID 5 handle unrecoverable sectors on a HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid-5

I'm going to set up a RAID 5 on 4 hard drives on my ubuntu system. I plan to use ext4 on a logic volume.

Suppose one disk reports an unrecoverable sector. How would RAID 5 handle this? My understanding is that if the system were to read a file that was partially lost on one disk, the RAID 5 would rebuild it on a different sector on that affected disk.

So my question is; is this true and also is there such a command (maybe `fsck`) that would scan the whole disk and rebuild any unrecoverable sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your RAID 5 configuration would recalculate the missing information using the parity information.

I guess your sector would remain pending unless a write command might replace the sector in the disk. The replacement would take place regardless of your RAID configuration.

I guess the RAID rebuilt will only appply when replacing disks. I assume that there is no repair or replacement mechanismen for single pending sectors.